# Multi udp sockets for multi ethernet ports

Tags: linux, udp, ethernet

I have linux running on a device with multiethernet ports and i have set each of them up now i have my udp echo server running on my linux. I have sent packets from packetsender application and received them back from the same port. It is as follows:

192.168.1.100

192.168.1.101

192.168.1.102

192.168.1.103 are the 4 ethernet ports

When I send packets to 192.168.1.100 and i get an echo back from this port and when I set my network up for the second port up and send the packets to 192.168.1.101 then I am getting an echo from 192.168.1.100 though they are delivered at 192.168.1.101 and I understood that the socket was binded to the first port by the kernel and if I want my multiport to have each socket binded to the port.What is to be done?Here is the code for the single port binding of the socket. Should i use select() and do the same binding stating the ip addresses of each port?Kernel is assigning the socket binded of its own choice.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");

    return 0;
}
*/


#include <stdio.h>      /* standard C i/o facilities */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* needed for atoi() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* defines STDIN_FILENO, system calls,etc */
#include <sys/types.h>  /* system data type definitions */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* socket specific definitions */
#include <netinet/in.h> /* INET constants and stuff */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* IP address conversion stuff */
#include <netdb.h>      /* gethostbyname */



/* this routine echos any messages (UDP datagrams) received */

#define MAXBUF 1024*1024

void echo( int sd ) {
    int len,n;
    char bufin[MAXBUF];
    struct sockaddr_in remote;

    /* need to know how big address struct is, len must be set before the
       call to recvfrom!!! */

    len = sizeof(remote);

    while (1) {
      /* read a datagram from the socket (put result in bufin) */
      n=recvfrom(sd,bufin,MAXBUF,0,(struct sockaddr *)&remote,&len);

      /* print out the address of the sender */
      printf("Got a datagram from %s port %d\n",
             inet_ntoa(remote.sin_addr), ntohs(remote.sin_port));

      if (n<0) {
        perror("Error receiving data");
      } else {
        printf("GOT %d BYTES\n",n);
    printf("%s\n",bufin);
        /* Got something, just send it back */

        sendto(sd,bufin,n,0,(struct sockaddr *)&remote,len);
    // ClUSTERING
      }
    }
}

/* server main routine */

int main() {
  int ld;
  struct sockaddr_in skaddr;
  int length;

  /* create a socket
     IP protocol family (PF_INET)
     UDP protocol (SOCK_DGRAM)
  */

  if ((ld = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 )) < 0) {
    printf("Problem creating socket\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* establish our address
     address family is AF_INET
     our IP address is INADDR_ANY (any of our IP addresses)
     the port number is assigned by the kernel
  */

  skaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  skaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  skaddr.sin_port = htons(0);

  if (bind(ld, (struct sockaddr *) &skaddr, sizeof(skaddr))<0) {
    printf("Problem binding\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  /* find out what port we were assigned and print it out */

  length = sizeof( skaddr );
  if (getsockname(ld, (struct sockaddr *) &skaddr, &length)<0) {
    printf("Error getsockname\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* port number's are network byte order, we have to convert to
     host byte order before printing !
  */
  printf("The server UDP port number is %d\n",ntohs(skaddr.sin_port));

  /* Go echo every datagram we get */
  echo(ld);
  return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You bound your socket to INADDR_ANY, which means any IP address. If that's not what you want, bind it to a specific IP address. But that way you need multiple sockets. The way you have it now, you don't.

Comment: Yeah, now I have bind to specific addresses that is fine... but now how can I handle two ports at a time? to receive packets simultaneously.

Comment: Either in seperate threads or in non-blocking mode with `select()`.

Comment: Oh yaa, seperate threads is of my choice i guess because I want to receive data at a time in both ports